# Thrust requirements from Saturn 1 rocket's first stage

Tags: thrust, saturn-i, cluster

What was the need / trigger to develop Saturn I rocket, and who defined / what dictated the thrust requirements from Saturn I, so that eight number of H1 engines had to be clustered to achieve that thrust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the origin of the [Saturn I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_I) was a US Department of Defense requirement to launch large communication and reconnaissance satellites:

> The Saturn project was started as one of a number of proposals to meet a new Department of Defense (DoD) requirement for a heavy-lift vehicle to orbit a new class of communications and "other" satellites. The requirements called for a vehicle capable of putting 20,000 to 40,000 pounds (9,100 to 18,100 kg) into orbit, or accelerating 13,200 to 26,200 pounds (6,000 to 11,900 kg) to trans-lunar injection.

For a given set of propellants, in this case RP-1 kerosene and liquid oxygen for the first stage, and liquid hydrogen and liquid oxygen for upper stages, it's straightforward to use [the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) to make rough estimates of the required thrust and fuel tankage for each stage to get a given payload to orbit. Wernher von Braun and his team did the math and worked out that they needed about 6.7 MN thrust on the first stage to build such a launcher. This was a reasonable fit for the F-1 engine currently under development, but the F-1 wouldn't be available in the needed timeframe.

As an alternative, they turned to an engine being developed as a simpler, more powerful version of the S-3D engine family used on the Atlas, Thor, and Jupiter missiles. [This was called the X-1 at the time, but evolved into the H-1.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_H-1) Given the target thrust for the first stage, and the expected performance of the H-1, 8 engines was the right number to use.

Comment: @ Russell. Your response has been precise. I have  a few "extended" doubts though. Considering the demands by DoD of launching "other" satellites with a specific mention of "trans-lunar" injection, is it possible that DoD in fact wanted to make an attempt to see if our weapons can reach moon? If so, they might even be planning to establish "Moon" as a weapon base?